# Pandoc escaping iframes during Markdown to HTML Convert

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert markdown files to html in a Jekyll blog.

I am passing these flags to pandoc `-t html5 --smart --section-divs --parse-raw` but it does not seem to render the iframe. Here is a [screenshot of what it produces.](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1l7B2k9yNY8/VYq4jtj6iyI/AAAAAAAAAAU/sQoZzp9OI3Y/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-06-24%2Bat%2B15.02.09.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction so that it ends up being rendered correctly?

Here is the iframe in the markdown file

```
<div class="scratch-preview">
<iframe allowtransparency="true" width="485" height="402" src="http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/embed/26818098/?autostart=false" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<img src="space-final.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin like jekyll-pandoc-plugin or jekyll-pandoc-multiple-formats ?

Comment: no that is in my gemfile and iv used homebrew to install pandoc as well.

Comment: could you post a snippet of code that surrounds that iframe?

Comment: sure iv updated the question.

I have used default kramdown and it renders fine but the issue is then I dont get id's added to things like `# Step 1: Sprites { .activity }`

Comment: <strike>writing up an answer</strike> doing more research, try adding `markdown="0"` attribute to your iframe for the time being. should work to prevent Kramdown from parsing it.

Comment: im afraid that doesnt work as I am using pandoc to convert. I did mention that when using kramdown it renders fine, however I get another issue with styling not being added to elements e.g. `# Step 1: Sprites { .activity }`

Comment: sorry, i've misread.

Comment: What's the output of `pandoc` directly converting the respective partial (i.e. without going through `jekyll`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been discussed on [github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2244#issuecomment-115353954).  The problem seems to be caused by indentation of the iframe being 4 spaces or more, causing it to be interpreted as code by markdown.

Comment: Interesting I shall give that a try. So this is just pandoc having the issue as I noticed if I use kramdown it renders it ok. I shall update you when I amend the indentation.

Comment: Tested it and your completely right thank you. I shall ping a thank you message on github as well.

Comment: Further more on that github issue they note `-f markdown_strict` as a pandoc flag works. I can confirm it does without needing to amend the indentation, however it does remove `# Introduction { .intro }` styling.